# Tryin to do two things in a Loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, setinterval

I wrote a script in Javascript with 2 functions.
Die first shows random pictures in an random position
This works fine

The second script has to "clear up" everthing and put everything back to the Startposition.

My script at this time:

```
function clearPics(){

    $("img[class^='mapic']").attr('src','empty100.jpg');
    $("img[class^='mapic']").attr("title",'');
    $("img[class^='mapic']").attr("alt",'');
}


    function makePics(){
// 1 Step take 5 different Pics
var MAAuswahlArr = [];
var AnzahlAnzeige = 5;
var lauf = AnzahlAnzeige
while (lauf > 0){
    var testvar = getRandomInt(0,MAArr.length-1);
    if (contains.call(MAAuswahlArr, testvar)){
    }else{
        MAAuswahlArr.push(testvar);
        lauf--;
    }
}

// 2 Step get 5 of 10 different positions 
var BildanzahlMax           = 10
var BildanzahlArr           = [];
var BildPositionenbesetzt   = 5;
lauf = BildPositionenbesetzt;
while (lauf > 0){
        var testvar = getRandomInt(0,BildanzahlMax);
        if (contains.call(BildanzahlArr, testvar)){
    }else{
        BildanzahlArr.push(testvar);
        lauf--;
    }
}   


// 3 step: take 5 Pics an put ist in the src the alt and title Tags  
  lauf = BildanzahlMax;
  while (lauf > 0){
  var className = "mapic"+lauf;
    if (contains.call(BildanzahlArr, lauf)){
        $('.'+className).attr('src',MAArr[lauf-1][2]);
        $('.'+className).attr("title",MAArr[lauf-1][1]);
        $('.'+className).attr("alt",MAArr[lauf-1][0]);
    }
  lauf--;
  }
// 4. step: make the Pics Hover
  $("img[class^='mapic']").hover(function() {
        var maName = $(this).attr("title");
        var mafunktion = $(this).attr("alt");
        $('.matextblock').html("<h3> Unser Team</h3> <p class='maName'>"+mafunktion+"</p><p class='maFunktion'>"+maName+"</p>");
        console.log('huhu rein');

    }, function() {
        $('.matextblock').html('');
    });
    return true;
    }
$(document).ready(function() {  
setInterval(function(){
   var done = makePics();
    console.log(done);  
    if (done){ 
        clearPics();
        //console.log('clear');
     }else{
        done = false;
    }
    },2000);
});
```

How can I run the script to 
a) make the Picture

b) wait 5 or n seconds

c) clear up

and go back to a) ?

Comment: So A) and C) is working, it's just the waiting part that's not? We can't know if we don't actually see the functions.

Comment: How do makePics() and clearPick() work? write you html,css and js as needed it's hard to imagine what you did.

Comment: a) and c) are 2 function thats run fine. for me.
I edi the completey script in a scond

Comment: So what you want it to run makePics, wait until that function is complete and then run clearPics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `done` variable should be declared outside of the anonymous function executed by `setInterval`. Right now it is redeclared every time the function fires, so the if/else branch is useless.

Exampel code:

```
$(function() {

    var pictureShown = false;
    var interval = 5000;

    setInterval(function () {
        if(pictureShown) {
            clearPics();
        } else {
            makePics();
            pictureShown = true;
            //OR, if makePics returns true:
            //pictureShown = makePics();
        }
    }, interval);

});
```

**Edit:** I adapted your setInterval code to make it work, but the whole setup could be much simplified - see Adder's response.

Answer (score 1):

Thank Folks I got it

this is my Code witch workls fine for me.
Ich change the positio for the clearPics funtion.

So I do not have to wait 5 Seconds to the next Pictures :-?

```
var done = false;
var interval = 5000;
$(document).ready(function() {  
    setInterval(function(){
        //done = makePics();
        if (done){ 
            done = false;
        }else{
            clearPics();
            done = makePics();
        }
        console.log(done);  
    },interval);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the code can be simplified. As far as I can tell from the info on the functions you gave out.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    makePics();  
    setInterval(function(){
        clearPics();
        var done = makePics();
    },2000);
}
```

This will clear the pics first, and then redisplay a new set of Pics with makePics, every 2000 ms.